# how to extract data in nested list/vector clojure

Tags: clojure

I have parse xml and get the following result

```
(({:tag :Column,
   :attrs {:Name "VENDOR_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
   :content nil}
  {:tag :Column,
   :attrs {:Name "RETAILER_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
   :content nil}
  {:tag :Column,
   :attrs {:Name "ITEM_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
   :content nil})
 ({:tag :Column,
   :attrs {:Name "Store_Key", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
   :content nil}))
```

then how to convert it to the following, basically I want to extract the value of key :attrs in nested list.

```
    (
    ({:Name "VENDOR_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
     {:Name "RETAILER_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"},
     {:Name "ITEM_KEY", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"}),
    ({:Name "Store_Key", :Type "Int", :NotNull "Yes"})
    )
```

Comment: (map :attrs (first result))

Comment: @hsestupin, your solution only get the data from the first list in the list, the example has 2 lists in the list. I could combine yours with (map :attr (second result)), but what if I have 10 lists in the list?

Comment: @DanielWu `(map #(map :attrs %) result)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so yes right here your solution as 
 [hsestupin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906677/hsestupin) said

```
(map #(map :attrs %) result)
```

i am assuming result is your input data.